# Manga where a guy has an inter dimensional clown/jester friend

Tags: story-identification, magic, manga

- His clown friend can summon a roulette wheel which drains a lot of his power but can double the power of the main character.
- The main character lives in an advanced society where there is a human created black hole which caused mutations turning animals into monsters but also gave people superpowers.
- The superpowers are powered by the soul and people also make weapons that use soul power of the user to function.

Comment: That sounds like some kind of Final Fantasy or JoJo's Bizarre Adventure setup.

Answer (score 2):

The manga [*Battle Frenzy*](https://battlefrenzy.fandom.com/wiki/Battle_Frenzy_Wiki)
matches all criteria.

[image: Front cover of Battle Frenzy]

> Amidst a disaster, an orphan contracts a sickness.
> In his waking hours, he is tormented by his ailment, but when he slumbers, there is infinite darkness.
>
> One day, when he was five years old, a strange Fate Trickster appeared in his dreams. Ten years later, he dreams of becoming a lord. To do so, he takes a chance to trade his fate!
>
> That day, Wang Zhong once again stood at the gates of the Tianjing Heroic Soul Academy. He was about to start a brand new life.

....

> An orphan who nearly died when he was 2 years old is cured with the help of the Fate/Destiny Stone and the Playful Clown, Simba grows up to become a battle expert.

[image: Playful Clown Simba]

As can be read in [the webnovel](https://novel1s.com/battle-frenzy-c5.html), Simba indeed initially controls the Fate Roulette, which has an effect on Wang Zhong's "soul sea".

> Wang Zhong scratched his head. Simba had started that demonic roulette all by himself and aside from the effects it had caused on his soul sea, Simba had shrunk into a palm-sized version of himself. He’d paid a steep cost to forcefully spin the roulette and now lay dormant. If they tried it again, it would likely cost his life. Wang Zhong could only look after himself from now on.
>
> The crack on the seal had widened a bit. Even though his soul power had only risen to 50 grassos, its significance was completely different for Wang Zhong!

Comment: Are you able to [edit] more details in as to why this matches? Try listing examples from the manga itself. Like names of the clown friend, or the superpowers. That then means people don't need to click the link, and might be more likely vote on your answer

Answer (score 1):

Might be [Flame of Recca](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flame_of_Recca).

One of the characters, called [Joker](https://flameofrecca.fandom.com/wiki/Joker), dresses like a jester and can create black holes as an attack.

There are also mutated monsters (such as [a man turned into a man-lion beast](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c2HiI-HWezY)), but those are not created through black holes. Some monsters (zombies, I think) are biological experiments.