# Light novel involving a main character who fights in tournaments using a weapon that is like a wheel

Tags: story-identification, novel

I'm searching the name of a light novel, which I have forgotten. What I remember is that the main character likes to use a weapon that is like a wheel, which spins and each time it hits someone, it becomes faster and stronger. I remember that in the novel there is a part where he participates in a tournament. In the tournament, nearly all the participants don't want to fight against him because of this wheel. One of the winners has spatial abilities. He has a girlfriend who has something like an ice maiden with chains as her "stand". Anyway, I have found it, It was Battle Frenzy, is someone is interested in it.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. Regarding _"spacial abilities"_ though, did you mean special abilities? Or spatial?

Comment: [This Battle Frenzy](https://manhuaes.com/manga/battle-frenzy/)? Now you've identified it you can add your own answer to help anyone else who might be looking for it.

Comment: @Shiro3023 (I've provided a basic answer based on your identification of the work). You can feel free to write your own, suggest edits to mine, and approve either one by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

Answer (score 5):

In case Shiro3023 does not return, they found that the comic was *[Battle Frenzy](https://www.novelupdates.com/series/battle-frenzy/)*

[image: Display image for Battle Frenzy]

> Amidst a disaster, an orphan contracts a sickness.
>
> In his waking hours, he is tormented by his ailment, but when he slumbers, there is infinite darkness.
>
> One day, when he was five years old, a strange Fate Trickster appeared in his dreams. Ten years later, he dreams of becoming a lord. To do so, he takes a chance to trade his fate!
>
> That day, Wang Zhong once again stood at the gates of the Tianjing Heroic Soul Academy. He was about to start a brand new life.

Comment: Also a suggested answer at https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/229716/manga-where-a-guy-has-an-inter-dimensional-clown-jester-friend/235604#235604